# Basis for $F(X, \mathbb{C})$ where $X$ is a non-empty finite set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a finite non-empty set and let $V = F(X, \mathbb{C})$ denote the set of all functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{C}$. For $x \in X$, let $\chi x$ denote the
characteristic function of the singleton subset $\{ x \}$ of $X$. Show that $\{ \chi x : x \in X \}$ is a basis
for $V$.

I get that the $\chi x$ are linearly independent. This can be shown by taking
$$ \{ x_{1},x_{2},\ldots, x_n \} =X,$$
then if
$$ a_1 \chi x_1+a_2 \chi x_2 + \ldots a_n \chi x_n =0, $$  applying this to each of the elements of $X$ we get that each $a_i$ is equal to $0$.

But how do we show that it spans ?

Answer (score 1):

Take $f \in \operatorname{F}(X,C)$ and suppose that $X = \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. Then check that
$$f = f(x_1)\chi_{x_1} + \cdots + f(x_n)\chi_{x_n}.$$

Comment: so it means the field  over which vector space defined should be compleX numbers ??

Comment: If not, how is defined the sum and scalar multiplication on $V$?